# Angular 2 - changing css selector on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Here is my Angular 2 app:

```
//root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div class="{{item.itemclass}}" id="lists" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div class="item" (click)="selectItem(item)">{{item}}</div>
        <div>{{item.itemclass}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class App {
  name:string;
  items: any[];
  itemclass : string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.items = [
      'lorem',
      'ipsum',
      'sit',
      'trump :D'
    ];
    this.itemclass = '';
  }
  selectItem(item){
    console.log(item);
    item.itemclass = "active";
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When the click event `selectItem` is triggered, it is supposed to change the `itemclass`. However, nothing happens.

Find my app at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I8i0xF1s3NsFDi1rHI6K).

All I want to achieve is: when a user clicks on a item it would have an `active` css selector, and when another item is clicked, it would simply toggle and all the siblings will not have the `active` css class any more.

But it isn't working properly. How to do it in Angular 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your requirement. Please check the plunker in the question.

Here, I used, `[class.active]="item == itemclass"`, **this binds the class name `active` to the current selected item.**

these `[class.active]` `[]`, brackets are one way binding from controller to view.

`this.itemclass = item;` **this line assigns the current item to item class, which we checked in the view.**

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div id="lists" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div class="item" [class.active]="item == itemclass" (click)="selectItem(item)">{{item}}</div>
        <div>{{item.itemclass}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

**Class:**

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  items: any[];
  itemclass : string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.items = [
      'lorem',
      'ipsum',
      'sit',
      'trump :D'
    ];
    this.itemclass = '';
  }
  selectItem(item){

    this.itemclass = item;
    console.log(this.itemclass);
  }
}
```

[Here is the solved plunker link.](https://plnkr.co/edit/WwVLTkjxnXlGQ9oDyopT?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have multiple selects and store them somewhere:
There you have `active` array that stores the state (on/off) of all the items you have.
During construction phase you map `active` array to `false`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div class="{{item.itemclass}}" id="lists" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <div class="item"  [class.active]="active[i]" (click)="active[i] = !active[i]">{{item}}</div>
        <div>{{item.itemclass}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class App {
  name:string;
  items: any[];
  itemclass : string;
  active: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.items = [
      'lorem',
      'ipsum',
      'sit',
      'trump :D'
    ];
    this.itemclass = '';
    this.active.length = this.items.length;
    this.active.map(e=> false);

  }

}
```